# Calculating distance from point to feature returned from layer query using ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: distance, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, angular

I have a project where a user clicks on a map and I filter to show all features from a layer that are within a certain distance of the point clicked.  That part of things works fine.  What is not working are my attempts to calculate the distance from the point clicked to the queried feature location.  I've isolated the issue to my geometry service:

```
export class GeometryService {
public geodesicUtils;
public Point;

constructor() {
    this.initialize
}

private async initialize() {
    try{
        [
            this.geodesicUtils,
            this.Point
        ] = await loadModules([
            GeodesicUtilsModule,
            PointModule
        ]);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

public getDistance(from: {x: number, y: number}, to: {x: number, y: number}, unit?: string): esri.GeodesicDistanceResult {
    const fromPoint = new this.Point(from);
    const toPoint = new this.Point(to);
    const result: esri.GeodesicDistanceResult = this.geodesicUtils.geodesicDistance(fromPoint, toPoint, unit);
    return result;
}
```

Essentially the app just stops when instantiating a new point.  When I break point through it just goes off into some obfuscated dojo nightmare code and never returns a result.  No exception is thrown, no error displayed it just disappears into purgatory never to be heard from again. Below is the code that initiates the call to the service:

```
this.queryResults = results.features.map((feature: any) => {
    const deviceFeature: IElectricDeviceFeature = this.electricDeviceFeatures.find((electricFeature: IElectricDeviceFeature) => electricFeature.value == feature.attributes.assetgroup);
    const toPoint: {x: number, y: number} = {
      x: feature.geometry.longitude,
      y: feature.geometry.latitude,
    }
    const calculatedDistance: esri.GeodesicDistanceResult = this.geometryService.getDistance(fromPoint, toPoint, this.searchState.units);
    return {
      attributes: feature.attributes,
      geometry: feature.geometry,
      symbol: deviceFeature.symbol,
      label: deviceFeature.label,
      distance: calculatedDistance.distance,
      distanceUnits: this.searchState.units,
    };
  });
```

This is an angular 8 app using the arc gis 4.14 javascript api.  It also uses some ngrx for statemanagement although that is not relevant here.